# Facebook API returns empty response only from specific IP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

Suddenly simple Facebook Graph API calls started to return an empty result. The node I'm calling is a simple search page by name:

```
`https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=page&fields=profile_picture,username,id,name,likes,category,talking_about_count&access_token=<APP_TOKEN>&limit=10&q=stackoverflow`
```

It just started to return an empty result set when called from my server:

```
{"data":[]}
```

When I'm calling it from my personal computer browser, it works just fine.

I don't see any notification in Facebook Manage Apps page. What can be the reason? Is there any way I can see any error in this Graph API result?

UPDATE: suddenly it started working again, after it was down for at least 2 hours. Is there any way I can make these calls through client side JS? Any way to avoid to exposure of my APP_TOKEN?

UPDATE2: It stopped working again, and although I haven't identified the reason, I did figure when replacing the  with a , it does work. The documentation actually says to use an APP_TOKEN.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem here, but unfortunately it's been going on for way more than 2 hours, close to 2 days.

Comment: Check my update2. I've managed to make it work in the meantime using an <USER_TOKEN> instead of an <APP_TOKEN> (although documentation states to use an APP_TOKEN)